# "independence" in definition of complex Gaussian distribution

Tags: distributions

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution)

> the family of complex normal distributions characterizes complex
>   random variables whose real and imaginary parts are jointly normal,[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution)
>   i.e., normally distributed and **independent**.

The definition in the same article is

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $vec[X Y]$ is a $2k$-dimensional normal random vector. Then we say that the complex random vector
>   $$
>     Z = X + iY \, 
> $$
>   has the complex normal distribution.

Does "independent" mean independence between random variables $X$ and $Y$, or linear independence between vectors $X$ and $Y$ in vector space $\mathbb{R}^k$ ?

If the former, why  doesn't the definition require $X$ and $Y$ to be independent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It means the random variables are statistically independent.

Comment: If it means s the random variables are statistically independent, why doesn't the definition require X and Y to be independent?

Comment: The page considers several different cases.  In some cases, X and Y are independent, and in other cases they are not.  I  would say that the first sentence on that page is misleading.

Comment: " the first sentence is misleading", do you mean the definition of complex Gaussian distribution shouldn't require independence between X and Y?

Comment: Yes.  Looking at the history of that page, the comment about independence was added well after the rest of the page was written.